# Rails - Froala editor plugins aren't loading when I first load the page, how do I load the plugins before initializing the editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, froala

I have froala editor installed on my rails 4.2 app. I'm not using the gem because I have added extra custom buttons to the toolbar. I have all the froala files in /public/froala (know its not best practice but its still easy to update this way and its the only way I could get the custom buttons to work).

I have set the toolbar defaults like so

```
jQuery ->
          $('#edit').froalaEditor({
            toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', '|', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertTable', '|', 'quote', 'insertHR', 'undo', 'redo', 'clearFormatting', 'selectAll', 'html'],
            imageResizeWithPercent: true,
            imageDefaultWidth: 70,
            imageInsertButtons: ['imageByURL']
```

But I have one problem. The toolbar doesnt have the right buttons displayed when I load the page, only after I refresh the page once does the buttons I set display. I asked their support and showed them a video and they told me I don't have the plugins loaded when I first load the page. They said to make sure I load the plugins before initializing the editor.

How can I get that done?

Comment: Have you tried to add 'data-no-turbolink' to link which refers to editor?

`= link_to edit_post_path(post), data: { no_turbolink: true }`

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem

Comment: temporarily disable turbolinks altogether to see if the issue is caused by them or not. For how to do it see e.g. http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4

Comment: Are you using their gem? If so, have you added the plugin files to you `application.js` and `application.css` as shown here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that has the same problem its trubolinks that is causing it. I disabled turbolinks and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

**In your Gemfile**

```
gem 'wysiwyg-rails'
```

**In application.css**

```
/*
 *= require froala_editor.min.css
 *= require froala_style.min.css
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require plugins/code_view.min.css
 *= require plugins/draggable.min.css
 *= require plugins/file.min.css
 *= require plugins/table.min.css
 *= require plugins/video.min.css
 *= require plugins/colors.min.css
 *= require plugins/image.min.css
 *= require plugins/image_manager.min.css
 *= require plugins/line_breaker.min.css
 *= require plugins/quick_insert.min.css
*/
```

**In application.js**

```
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/align.min.js
//= require plugins/code_beautifier.min.js
//= require plugins/code_view.min.js
//= require plugins/draggable.min.js
//= require plugins/entities.min.js
//= require plugins/file.min.js
//= require plugins/font_size.min.js
//= require plugins/font_family.min.js
//= require plugins/image.min.js
//= require plugins/image_manager.min.js
//= require plugins/inline_style.min.js
//= require plugins/line_breaker.min.js
//= require plugins/link.min.js
//= require plugins/lists.min.js
//= require plugins/paragraph_format.min.js
//= require plugins/paragraph_style.min.js
//= require plugins/quick_insert.min.js
//= require plugins/table.min.js
//= require plugins/video.min.js
//= require plugins/colors.min.js
//= require plugins/quote.min.js
```

Then try your code

```
$('#edit').froalaEditor({
            toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', '|', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertTable', '|', 'quote', 'insertHR', 'undo', 'redo', 'clearFormatting', 'selectAll', 'html'],
            imageResizeWithPercent: true,
            imageDefaultWidth: 70,
            imageInsertButtons: ['imageByURL']
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: sorry to bother you but your `.froalaEditor` initialisation is never closed i cant create and edit suggest just for `});`

Answer (score 0):

By my estimation you have an issue loading jQuery on initial load of the page. Please make sure you have in

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'wysiwyg-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
```

make sure require jQuery is before `//= require_tree .` also all plug ins have to be before tree. Following is my full list of requires and it works fully.

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/align.min.js
//= require plugins/char_counter.min.js
//= require plugins/code_beautifier.min.js
//= require plugins/code_view.min.js
//= require plugins/colors.min.js
//= require plugins/entities.min.js
//= require plugins/font_family.min.js
//= require plugins/font_size.min.js
//= require plugins/fullscreen.min.js
//= require plugins/image.min.js
//= require plugins/image_manager.min.js
//= require plugins/line_breaker.min.js
//= require plugins/link.min.js
//= require plugins/lists.min.js
//= require plugins/paragraph_format.min.js
//= require plugins/paragraph_style.min.js
//= require plugins/quick_insert.min.js
//= require plugins/save.min.js
//= require plugins/table.min.js
//= require plugins/url.min.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```